# Search items by its condition on Amazon?

Tags: search, amazon

In Amazon, there are some amazon URL parameters to filter the item result on the amazon search, such as `&pct-off=50-75`.

I wonder if there is any way or a URL param to filter and show only a specific condition (e.g. "acceptable") items on the result?